# How to rectify this boolean error in c# code?

Tags: c#, mvvm

How can I rectify this error?

> bool does not contain a definition for 'Ok' and no accessible
>   extension method 'Ok' accepting a first argument of type 'bool?' could
>   be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

This is my code

```
if (openFolderDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Ok && viewModel.OpenFolderCommand.CanExecute(openFolderDialog.SelectedPath)) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Can you show the exact compilation error? you edited out a few parts which might be necessary for us to understand. Further, have you imported the namespace for DialogResult?

Comment: Also sharing your imports (using) might be helpful

Comment: Yeah ...I rectified it now....By changing "DialogResult.OK" into "System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK"...anyways thank you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the correct "using" sentence at the top of your file.
As you mentioned, it's System.Windows.Forms.

Comment: yeah ...even if I add the line System.Windows.Forms. at the top of my file ,I didn't get,...only if I change it here too like "System.Windows.Forms DialogResult.OK" ...I got it.